# It is said that using sleep() is poor design, but what about waiting for hardware to settle?

Tags: embedded, sleep

I am using `sleep()` in two ways in my current embedded (real time) software design:

1. To throttle a processing loop, but this is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081431/best-way-to-slow-down-a-thread-is-using-sleep-ok), and as pointed out thread priority will most likely answer very well for that.
2. Waiting for hardware to "settle". Lets say I am writing an interface to some hardware. Communications with the hardware is all good, but I want to change its mode and I know it only takes a small number of instruction cycles to do it. I am using a `sleep(1);` to pause briefly to allow for this. I could setup a loop that keeps pinging it until I receive a valid response, but this would arguably be harder to read (much more code) and, in fact, slower because of data transfer times. In fact I could probably do a `usleep(100)` or less in my case.

So my question is, is this a good practice? And if not, is there a better/efficient alternative?

Comment: You could have a hybrid solution where you sleep for the expected amount of time the operation should take (avoid spin lock and data transfer as you said), wake up, check that the operation completed (just in case the operation takes a little longer this time). Sleep again (maybe for less time) if the operation is still pending and repeat.

Comment: I think that using sleep() is always wrong. But if you know this, and you are using sleep() anyway, then it means that it's right

Comment: What OS or RTOS are you referring to?  Regarding it being "said"; citation needed.  Who said that, where, and what was their justification, and does it apply in the instance you describe?

Comment: The question is language-agnostic. It also is far too broad. The only correct answer would be not helpful: "It depends.".

Comment: When running on the raw metal, I think it's bad style to use a blocking style of coding if real-time responses are needed. If your system has no real-time requirements, you'll just get poor Quality of Service by using blocking design (sleeps are usually a sign/smell of blocking code).

Comment: Without a specific system in mind, this question is way too broad. Linux? RTOS? Bare metal MCU?

Comment: @Lundin I mentioned that it is embedded and real time in the first line of the post. In this case (for my code) I don't believe the OS is relevant it could be QNX, Linux or bare metal I would still ask the same of all of them.

Comment: @Jack lol ... maybe true :o

Comment: @code_fodder It is very relevant: when answering, people need to know if context switches even exist on your system, if there are other processes/programs except your running, etc etc. On a bare metal system it might make perfect sense to sleep() if your program has nothing better to do: you aren't sharing the CPU with anyone else anyhow. Etc etc.

Comment: @Lundin ah, ok. In this case the embedded system is real time and during config/init time. There are other processes running but I don't really care about them so much since nothing is waiting on my task, plus a sleep() allows a context switch anyway.

Comment: @code_fodder A sleep may or may not allow a context switch. Again, it depends on the system. Sleep is defined by POSIX but it will not be defined in misc RTOS.

Comment: @Lundin That is a fair point : ) In my case sleep() allows context switch.

Comment: Understand what choices are available to you for that system and operating system.  sleep or a delay of some form is always there.  an interrupt sometimes, a pollable status sometimes, sometimes a fire and forget, it finishes when it finishes and you dont care, you just initiate it.  THEN weigh the pros and cons then pick one, maybe try each as part of picking one.  saying that one of them is always right and one is always wrong...is wrong...there is no right answer. "it depends"

Answer (score 2):

**Callback**

The most ideal solution to this would be to have the hardware notify you when a particular operation is complete through some form of callback/signal.

When writing production code, I would almost always favor this solution above all others. Of course this is provided that the api you are using exposes such methods.

**Poll**

If there is no way for you to receive such events then the only other option would be for you to check if the operation has completed. The most naive solution would be one that constantly checks (spin-lock).

However, if you know roughly how long an operation should take you could always sleep for that duration, wake-up, check operation status then sleep again or continue.

If you are 100% sure about the timings and can guarantee that your thread is not woken up early then you can rely solely on sleep.

**Poor Design?**

I wouldn't necessarily say that using sleep for this task is poor design. Sometimes you have no other choice. I would say that to rely solely on sleep is poor design when you cannot guarantee timing because you can not be 100% sure that the operation you are waiting for has in fact completed.

Comment: +1, What you say makes the most sense so far (of what I have read). I am in the unfortunate position where I get no response from this "mode change" command, but as you say the time taken is relatively well known (way less then a millisecond). Also since this is "setup/config time" a millisecond is ok for now.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux I use [sigsuspend](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html) it suspends the software until it receives a signal.

### Example

My main thread needs a data, but this data isn't ready, so main thread is suspended.

Other thread reads the data and when it finishes, it fires a signal.

Now then main thread continues and it has the data ready.

**If you use sleep the data can be ready or not.**

Comment: Actually I like the idea... but I got no reply from this particular mode change command so there is not much for me to wait for. The only thing I could do is send a different query command to check it is working.